# Segmentation fault: randomly removing elements from 2d vector

Tags: c++, vector

Given a 2D vector, I want to randomly retrieve and then delete an element, repeating this process until the vector is empty.

However, my code returns a `Segmentation fault: 11` error when run, at different points in the loop every time. This tells me that the code is trying to retrieve an element from an index that no longer exists, and that I've been thinking about ways to either parse indices or delete elements incorrectly.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {

    int X_LENGTH = 4;
    int Y_LENGTH = 4;
    std::vector<std::vector<long> > arrayCellDistance(X_LENGTH, std::vector<long>(Y_LENGTH, 0));

    // Assign values to array, print them out in order
    for (int i = 0; i < X_LENGTH; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < Y_LENGTH; j++) {
            arrayCellDistance[i][j] = (i+j)/2 + i*j;
            std::cout << "arrayCellDistance[" << i << "][" << j << "] = " << arrayCellDistance[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "===============================================" << std::endl;

    int x, y;
    srand(time(NULL));

    while (!arrayCellDistance.empty()) {

        y = (rand() % (int)(arrayCellDistance.size())); // Rand from 0 to number of rows
        x = (rand() % (int)(arrayCellDistance[y].size())); // Rand from 0 to number of columns in row

        // 'Retrieve' value from array and then delete this value
        std::cout << "arrayCellDistance[" << x << "][" << y << "] = " << arrayCellDistance[x][y] << std::endl;

        arrayCellDistance[y].erase(arrayCellDistance[x].begin() + 1); // Remove element

    }

    return 0;
}
```

When printing out the matrix after removal, I get this output:

```
arrayCellDistance[0][1] = 0
0 1 1 0 
2 3 5 
1 3 6 8 
1 5 8 12 
arrayCellDistance[2][2] = 6
0 1 1 0 
2 3 5 
1 6 8 
1 5 8 12 
arrayCellDistance[1][1] = 3
0 1 1 0 
2 5 
1 6 8 
1 5 8 12 
arrayCellDistance[2][2] = 8
0 1 1 0 
2 5 
1 8 
1 5 8 12 
arrayCellDistance[1][0] = 2
Segmentation fault: 11
```

As you can see, there is a segmentation fault when the program tries to remove the `2` in the second row - so, since there is still a "row" vector present, should it not be able to still access any row?

Comment: `arrayCellDistance.size() + 1 - 1`? Why not simply `arrayCellDistance.size()`?

Comment: Consider your condition statement `while(!arrayCellDistance.empty())` Does that handle the case where the first level vector is not empty, but one of the second level vectors is and you then try to remove an element from a second level vector?

Comment: @Borgleader good catch - the random function produces integers in the range `[0, arrayCellDistance.size()]` when that `+1` is included, but also tries to access indices out of bounds, hence the `-1` was added to change the range to  `[0, arrayCellDistance.size() - 1]`

Comment: @ChristopherPisz am I wrong in thinking that when all elements in a second level vector are erased, the second-level vector itself is erased?

Comment: @Daniel the second-level vector would remain and it would be empty, but it is still there. So, if you try to erase from it again, I imagine you'd make the computer angry.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz probably not a great implementation, but from your comment, shouldn't this code below work? `y = (rand() % (int)(arrayCellDistance.size())); while (arrayCellDistance[y].empty()) { y = (rand() % (int)(arrayCellDistance.size())); } x = (rand() % (int)(arrayCellDistance[y].size()));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a compiler handy right now, but I think you are looking for something like:

```
while (!arrayCellDistance.empty())
{
    y = (rand() % (int)(arrayCellDistance.size() ));    // Rand from 0 to number of rows

    if( arrayCellDistance[y].empty() )
    {
        // Error - Contained empty second-level vector initially.
        break;
    }

    x = (rand() % (int)(arrayCellDistance[y].size() )); // Rand from 0 to number of columns in row

    // Get value from array and display
    std::cout << "arrayCellDistance[" << x << "][" << y << "] = " << arrayCellDistance[x][y] << std::endl;

    // Remove element of second-level vector
    arrayCellDistance[y].erase( arrayCellDistance[y].begin() + x );

    // Remove empty first-level vector
    if( array[y].empty() )
    {
        arrayCellDistance.erase( arrayCellDistance.begin() + y );
    }
}
```

We want to make sure we are handling empty second level vectors and not trying to erase from them after they become empty. So, this code removes an empty vector after it becomes empty.